# Silverlight Binding: User controls inside datagrid

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have a DataGrid in my silverlight app that has a few columns. A couple basic columns bound with no issues. One column has a UserControl in it and the XAML is as follows:

---

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" CanUserSort="True" Width="107">
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:StaticPageEnlistment EnlistmentName="{Binding SiteName}" Width="400" Height="150"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

---

So I have a public property that's a string called EnlistmentName that I have bound to the SiteName value. I use this same "{Binding SiteName}" in all my other colums with no issues, why can't the user control accept the same binding string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess you haven't implemented the `EnlistmentName` as a DependencyProperty.  You would do that like this in your StaticPageEnlistment UserControl like this:-

```
    public string EnlistmentName
    {
        get { return GetValue(EnlistmentNameProperty) as string; }
        set { SetValue(EnlistmentNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnlistmentNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "EnlistmentName",
                    typeof(string),
                    typeof(StaticPageEnlistment ),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: Anthony, you were 31 seconds quicker :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and it doesn't appear to have solved it. Besides, when I hard code a string into the property like EnlistmentName="Test String" the binding works fine so I don't think it's an isdsue with the user control not allowing binding.

Comment: Wait. Never mind...it's working now...I had to change my property to be the same as your as now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is EnlistmentName a DependencyProperty ? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(VS.95).aspx), the target of a binding must be a DependencyProperty.